# jQuery inline-edit on double-click?

Tags: jquery, inline-editing

I'm using a jquery plugin for inline editing. But i would like to activate edition on double-click and not on single click.

Here is a created jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/N5cvv/2/

Could you please tell me how to solve my problem?

Comment: Change `click` to `dblclick`.

Comment: sorry, Rocket, i had not seen your comment... Thank you too for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check this edition in your code**

```
.live( ['dblclick', 'mouseenter','mouseleave'].join(namespace+' '), function( event ) {
```

//in  every click make as dblclick

Comment: Thank you for help Sam but i don't see any changes in my code!

Comment: Understood, Sam! Thanks for the heads-up!