# Making inline edit (based on previous post & code) list (my modification) sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I made a few changes to the jsFiddle of another question here:

[jQuery inline-edit on double-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282387/jquery-inline-edit-on-double-click)

[I created a fork of that question's jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jex4/)

to create a list:

```
function Create() {
  jQuery('<li><div style="width:100%;display:block;"><span class="editable">Click to edit</span></div></li>').appendTo('div#pl_list');
}
```

But it's bulleted and I'd like for the list to be numbered and sortable via drag-n-drop - any idea how to accomplish that?

This is off-topic but any idea how to get the id of an edited element (at bottom of code, where an alert is displayed)?

UPDATE:
I added inline formatting to make the bullet list a numbered one, with [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jex4/2/). But I'm still at loss on how to implement drag-n-drop with sorting.

Answer (score 0):

To show numbers instead of bullets you can change the `list-style-type` css-property of the ul to `decimal`.

To make it sortable by drag'n'drop you can make use of the JQuery UI draggable/droppable functionality, see here:

- draggable: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/
- droppable: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/